# Why do these two items have the same barcode?

Tags: barcode

I am trying to build an iOS app that involves scanning barcodes and I came across this weird scenario where [this](https://www.upcdatabase.com/item/180854000101) api and [this](http://www.upcitemdb.com/upc/180854000101) api gave me different items for the same UPC-A barcodes.

Is it possible for two item issued in the same country to have the same UPC-A barcode or is this the APIs fault?

Here's the barcode image? It'll be great if someone can give me some general barcode guidelines. It's my first time dealing with barcodes.
[image]

Comment: Both pages seem to indicate *some* form of link to `Red Bull`, so I know which result I'd trust more, in this case.

Comment: Do you have an image of the barcode you are scanning what result each API gives for it?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The second one is a shower gel product, I don't think it's related to redbull xD

Comment: @MananMehta - but at the bottom of that result, it also states "UPC 180854000101 might be created by GS1 CA company,
Red Bull Canada, Ltd. · BC · V6 · Vancouver B 6M5 · CA." - so like I say, both indicate some association with `Red Bull`.

Comment: @MalcolmMcCaffery I have added the image :) And I haven't integrated the API yet but there are links to the results in the question :)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Great eye for detail!

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Do you have any api suggestions for getting item details from a barcode number?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about API's, but I was a 3rd party seller on Amazon, and it looks like that shower gel was sold on Amazon, and the website http://www.upcitemdb.com that was used to pull those results pulls data from Amazon, somehow. When you enter an item for sale on Amazon, some catergories require you to use a barcode in order to place an item for sale on Amazon. If an item does not have a barcode it is conceivable that the seller invented one simply to get their listing on Amazon. In this case, it looks like they entered the same barcode that RedBull has registered to them.

I also find it fishy that the website http://www.upcitemdb.com not only pulls data from Amazon, but uses Amazon ads, and is likely owned by an Amazon affiliate who has a vested interest in directing traffic to Amazon, not in displaying correct barcode information.